# How to change setTimeout start time point?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I write two `setTimeout` statements in CoffeeScript:

```
setTimeout ( -> DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>") ), 1000
setTimeout ( -> DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>") ), 1000
```

I want these statements to execute in order and have a 1 second interval.  But they execute at the same time.  Can we change the start time point of `setTimeout`?

Comment: Can you change the second duration to `2000`?

Comment: To be clear, Javascript is single-threaded.  Those two do not execute at the same time.

Comment: @AaronDufour is absolutely correct. All the answers an incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Call the second `setTimeout` from the callback of the first (more versatile):

```
setTimeout (->
    DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>")

    setTimeout (->
        DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>")
    ), 1000

), 1000
```

Or simply adjust the timeout values:

```
setTimeout ( -> DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>") ), 1000
setTimeout ( -> DISPLAY_AREA.append("<p>" + "> " + message + "</p>") ), 2000
```

Comment: Is this the only method to do it?

Comment: I offered two methods there, but there are other ways to accomplish this.  Is there a problem?

Comment: I think the first method is too complex and the second method isn't easy to maintain.Is there any other methods?

Comment: The other answer here has an alternative solution using `setInterval`, but that's even more complex.  You might want to look into async.js if you want to simplify this kind of pattern.

Comment: @MarioDu: If the first one is too complex then write a simple wrapper to hide the complexity, then you could say `delayed(1000, f1, f2)` to run them in order. The same technique can be used to make the second version easier to maintain. If the standard library doesn't do what you want then you're allowed to wrap it in your own functions which do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use some like this:

```
 function inOrder() {
   this.count = this.count+1 || 0; //static var for this function
   if (this.count == 0) {          
     setTimeout('alert("1")', 1000); //First function
   } else if (this.count == 1) {   
     setTimeout('alert("2")', 1000); //second function
   } else { 
     clearInterval(Int); //Clear interval
   }
 }
 var Int = setInterval(inOrder, 1000); //Global reference on Interval Id
```